# loop QHash by insert order

Tags: c++, qt, qhash

Is it possible to loop a QHash by the insert order? The method below seem to loop the hash by some other factor:

```
QHashIterator<QString, QString> i(hash);
while (i.hasNext()) {
    i.next();
    qDebug() << i.key() << ": " << i.value();
}
```

**EDIT:**

I figured it was impossible with QHash but what should I use instead?

Comment: If you want to iterate over insert order, why don't you use a QList?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

From [QHash](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qhash.html#details) documentation,

> QHash is unordered, so **an iterator's
>   sequence cannot be assumed to be
>   predictable**. If ordering by key is
>   required, use a [QMap](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmap.html)

So it is **not possible**.

If you want ordering based on the keys, use `QMap` instead..

Hope it helps..

Edit:

If you **don't** need `Key` and `Value` Logical mapping and just their values, you can use

```
QList<QPair<QString,QString>> pairs;
```

For e.g:

The first value can be obtained by

```
QString firstValue = pairs.at(0).first;
```

Similarly for the second value in the QPair,

```
QString secondValue = pairs.at(0).second;
```

And you can iterate over the `QList` **to retrieve the elements in the inserted order**..

Comment: Thanks, but I want to order the hash from the insert time not the key.

Comment: In that case, **it is not possible**.

Answer (score 1):

`QHash` doesn't remember your insert order.  It is designed for fast random access.  The order you get with the iterator is arbitrary.

Answer (score 0):

If you **only** insert elements (no element removal) in the `QHash` you could use an array/list in parallel. It is not a very elegant solution but what you want cannot be achieved with `QHash` container only.